# What is the correct regex format for pdf file type?

Tags: regex

Based on this code that I have which is applying regex on data type image, what is the correct way for applying the same regex for data type pdf?

```
base64.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify your question, to help us help you

Comment: The code above describes applying regex to data type image. The question is about applying the same regex for a data type pdf

Comment: seems the question is about [mime types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) `image\/\w+` is for different image formats `application\/pdf` for pdf

Comment: Very nice @NahuelFouilleul please post as answer and I will vote for your answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment, for more information [read link about MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type).

- `image\/\w+` pattern may be used to match different image formats
- for PDF naming is `application/pdf`, and regex pattern `application\/pdf`.